# SQL for finding free rooms during a specific time period

Tags: php, sql

I'm currently  working on a hotel booking service and I want to show all free rooms for a specific roomtype and hotel during a specific time period.
I've found what seemed to be a working query until I noticed that: if a room does not have any reservations at all it doesn't work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.id, 
            r.num, 
            r.NAME, 
            h.NAME, 
            h.city, 
            h.country 
FROM   room r 
   JOIN hotel h 
     ON r.hotel_id = h.id 
   JOIN room_type rt 
     ON r.room_type_id = rt.id 
WHERE  r.id NOT IN (SELECT room_id 
                    FROM   reservation 
                    WHERE  ( '$from' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date ) 
                        OR ( start_date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' ) 
                        OR '$from' = start_date) 
   AND $roomtype = rt.id 
   AND $hotel = h.id
```

This query will be used in a PHP script where "$from" is the user's chosen start of reservation date and $to is end of reservation etc.

Is there a way to make this query work even if a room has no reservations?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic for a not-free room is:

- The booking starts on or before the period in question ends.
- The booking ends on or after the period in question starts.

A not not-free room is available.  Let's apply this logic to your query:

```
SELECT r.id, r.num, r.name, h.name, h.city, h.country
FROM room r JOIN
     hotel h
     ON r.hotel_id = h.id JOIN
     room_type rt
     ON r.room_type_id = rt.id
WHERE rt.id = $roomtype AND
      h.id = $hotel AND
      r.id NOT IN (SELECT res.room_id 
                   FROM reservation res
                   WHERE '$from' <= end_date AND
                         '$to' >= start_date AND
                  );
```

Note:  You should be using parameters for values in your query, rather than munging query strings.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick reply. I applied your logic and now it finally works properly! Also makes a lot of sense to check rt.id and r.id before the subquery. Thanks :)

Comment: This isn't 100% correct. It will only pick up reservations that are FULLY covered by the query, not those which are partially covered.

Comment: @Drewster . . . You are misunderstanding something.  This picks up any overlap.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I only read it rather than running it so I could be wrong but it looks like the code picks up any reservation where the $to of the booking is before or equal to the end date of the reservation AND $from is >= to the start date. Doesn't that mean it would miss anything where $to <= end_date AND $to > start_date AND $from < start_date (i.e. a partial overlap) or the same on the other end. The logic I implemented for the same was that either $from or $to had to be between start_date and end_date.

Comment: @Drewster . . . I think you were right.  The explanation is correct but the variables were backwards in the logic.